# D3v4: add text to the center of d3.symbolCircle

Tags: d3.js, text, path, label

I am working with force layout where some nodes are circle and some are arcs. I have used d3.symbolCircle to create my circles and now I am trying to add text to only circles. I have these circles as paths and I am trying to add text at the center of these circles.

I could get the text which follows the outline of the circle but what I want the text to be at the center of the circle laid out horizontally.

This is my code

```
let cir = d3.symbol().size(300).type(d3.symbolCircle);

node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(nodes.filter(d => d.name))
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("id", d=> d.name)
                .attr("d", d => {return d.type === 'Dish' ? cir(d) : arc(d);})
                .on('mouseover', fade(0.1))
                .on('mouseout', fade(1))
                .on("click",stickNode)
                .call(d3.drag()
                  .on("start", dragstarted)
                  .on("drag", dragged)
                  .on("end", dragended));

   let text = svg.append("text")
       .attr("dy", 15);

   text.append("textPath")
       .attr("xlink:href",function(d){return '#'+d.name;})
       .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
       .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')

       .attr('fill', 'white')
       .attr("startOffset", '75%')
      .text(d => d.name)
```

Comment: If you want just a plain text in the middle of the circle (a path actually), just drop that `<textPath>` and append a regular `<text>`.

Comment: I tried doing `let text = node.append("text").attr("dy", 15).attr("xlink:href",function(d){return '#'+d.name;}) ` A text element is getting created inside the path. But it does not show up on the screen.

Comment: You cannot append a `<text>` to a `<path>`. What I meant was create a new enter selection or, alternatively, append both paths and texts to `<g>` elements.